# Add Number of Entires into Datepicker Fields

Tags: jquery, mysql, datepicker

I am currently making use of jQuery Datepicker to select a 'to' and 'from' range to filter down mysql search results.

What I would like is if I can somehow preread the mysql database, so when a user clicks on the datepicker, the pop-up calendar shows (maybe in parentheses) the number of items found in the database for each day. e.g.

```
     Jan   2013
M  T  W  T  F  S  S 
--------------------
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
  (1)(5)(8)
--------------------
8  9  10 11 12 13 14
        (9)(3)
--------------------
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
(1)(1)(5)(6)
--------------------
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
--------------------
29 30 31
(8)
--------------------
```

To explain a bit more, its a photo gallery application. I want to be able to choose a date range to show pictures from...but if the user does not know the dates of pictures and is just 'browsing', then having an indication on the calendar which days have photos (indicated by a number) then that would be better.

Maybe I could do it similarly to this, Day of year in content example: http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#daymods

I imagined at first a jquery function that queries the database for an array of photos and their date taken, summed up. But that might be consuming if there are many in there...so perhaps it could be done on the fly, i.e. when the datepicker is clicked and 1 month is shown, it has only queried for results of that month...but then if the month is changed, it would have to query again on the fly....

I think this might end up being beyond my capabilities, but we'll see.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic solution would be to get the total photo count for *all* dates and store them in an object. Even with years of data, if you're only storing a count for each day, I don't imagine this would eat up *too* much memory.

You can fetch the data with an Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   url: url,
   data: { date: date },
   success: success
});
```

where `url` is the URL to request from your web server and `success` is a callback that processes the response. You will need to write some server-side code to handle the request and return the data from MySQL in a format you can interpret easily with JavaScript, like JSON.

Once you have the data, you can use the datepicker's [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option to manipulate each date in the calendar before it is displayed. For example, you could add a tooltip containing the total number of photos for that date:

```
/* Assume data stored in var count */
$("#datepicker").datepicker(
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [ true, "", count[date] ];
    }
);
```

This is a gross over-simplification (you should do some kind of error-checking, for example), but you get the gist. There's a good example of this approach [here](http://stevethomas.com.au/jquery/jquery-datepicker-ajax-request-to-highlight-days-from-mysql.html).

If you are worried about memory consumption, you could pre-load only the current month's counts and send an Ajax request to update the data when the user changes the month or year visible in the datepicker:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker(
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        /* Ajax request */
    }
);
```

Comment: This looks great. I shall give it a go and see how I get on. I presume the `url` in the ajax call could be a php script? Not sure what I would put in the success bit though...

Comment: @j0nr Yes, `url` could certainly point to a PHP script. In the `success` callback you could simply create a JavaScript object to hold the results of the Ajax request.

Comment: OK, I'm going to really start showing my naivety. I can understand the call to the php script, but I don't know what I am doing with the results in `success`. Is there some examples/tutorials you could point me to? I mean, I could generate an array in the php script of date => qty but I don't know how to make that compatible with the jQuery bit. Thanks

Comment: @j0nr Your PHP code will return some data, preferably in a standard format like JSON. You need to make that data accessible to your datepicker. One way would be to create a global object and populate it in the `success` callback, e.g. `var count = {}; function success(data) { count = data; }`

Comment: Doh, just spotted you included a link to an example sorry. Will have a read through that first. Cheers.